# Why is the rake task being aborted when I try to migrate the Thinking Sphinx index?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I've manually created a database in MySQL:

```
mysql> create database sample_app_development;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Ran this to test:

```
rake db:create
sample_app_development already exists
```

Got error when I when I ran `rake thinking_sphinx:index`

```
rake aborted!
Table 'sample_app_development.users' doesn't exist
```

How does the table not exist when it says that I have just created one and that it does exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in Jergason's answer - you've only created the database, not all the tables. If this is an app you're loading for the first time, then you'll probably want to run the following command to load the full schema:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

Otherwise, to update to the latest schema via migrations:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

The database named `sample_app_development` exists, but are you sure the table `users` is created when you run the rake task? The code you show will just create the database, not the tables inside it.